# Does argument (collection) to invokeAll depend on queue size?

Tags: java

As far as I know I can submit a collection of callable threads to invokeAll and threadpool will execute all the tasks (Running tasks equal to thread pool size in parallel at any given point).

But do I really need to take care of queue overflow while I use invokeall?

Comment: *"take care of queue overflow"*--which queue do you mean?

Comment: Every threadpool has an internal queue where tasks are held before submission. So, suppose i create a collection of callable tasks of size 10000 and then i submit it to invokeall. I am just curious if there is any chance that few of these tasks will be lost owing to limited queue size.

Comment: If you construct the executor with bounded queue, submitting "extra" tasks will call `rejectedExecution()` of `RejectedExecutionHandler` provided on executor creation, or throw `RejectedExecutionException` if no handler specified.

Comment: I am not creating custom executor its all default Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5). Does default uses unbounded queue?

Comment: yes, by default unbounded `LinkedBlockingQueue` is used.

Comment: Thanks sasha..this is what i was looking for. Sorry,Could have looked it by myself. So, when i use invokeAll(c) it copies all callables to its internal queue and then processes one by one?

Comment: more exactly, `invokeAll()` sends each task to executor (which either starts executing it immediately or put in the queue, depending on availability of thread in a pool), then blocks until they all are processed, or externally cancelled, or terminated with exception.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your code and business requirements. The [javadoc for ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) states the following use cases with regards to the queue:

> There are three general strategies for queuing:
>
> **Direct handoffs**. A
>   good default choice for a work queue is a SynchronousQueue that hands
>   off tasks to threads without otherwise holding them. Here, an attempt
>   to queue a task will fail if no threads are immediately available to
>   run it, so a new thread will be constructed. This policy avoids
>   lockups when handling sets of requests that might have internal
>   dependencies. Direct handoffs generally require unbounded
>   maximumPoolSizes to avoid rejection of new submitted tasks. This in
>   turn admits the possibility of unbounded thread growth when commands
>   continue to arrive on average faster than they can be processed.
>
> **Unbounded queues**. Using an unbounded queue (for example a
>   LinkedBlockingQueue without a predefined capacity) will cause new
>   tasks to wait in the queue when all corePoolSize threads are busy.
>   Thus, no more than corePoolSize threads will ever be created. (And the
>   value of the maximumPoolSize therefore doesn't have any effect.) This
>   may be appropriate when each task is completely independent of others,
>   so tasks cannot affect each others execution; for example, in a web
>   page server. While this style of queuing can be useful in smoothing
>   out transient bursts of requests, it admits the possibility of
>   unbounded work queue growth when commands continue to arrive on
>   average faster than they can be processed.
>
> **Bounded queues**. A bounded
>   queue (for example, an ArrayBlockingQueue) helps prevent resource
>   exhaustion when used with finite maximumPoolSizes, but can be more
>   difficult to tune and control. Queue sizes and maximum pool sizes may
>   be traded off for each other: Using large queues and small pools
>   minimizes CPU usage, OS resources, and context-switching overhead, but
>   can lead to artificially low throughput. If tasks frequently block
>   (for example if they are I/O bound), a system may be able to schedule
>   time for more threads than you otherwise allow. Use of small queues
>   generally requires larger pool sizes, which keeps CPUs busier but may
>   encounter unacceptable scheduling overhead, which also decreases
>   throughput.